# Fetch Recurring Job Details from Hangfire Scheduler which is using Mongo DB

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, hangfire

I have to display the Hangfire background job details which are created in Mongo DB, Is there any built in functions to query the job details ?
I am using .Net core Hangfire Nuget

Comment: I think it's better to read the Nuget package documentation first. If there is such method you should be able to find it there.

Answer (score 0):

If I read it correctly, you should find your relevant collections in the `databaseName`, and `_prefix`, that you set. The collections are named: `_prefix + ".notifications"`, `_prefix + ".jobGraph"`, `_prefix + ".schema"`, `_prefix + ".server"`

Source: https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/Hangfire.Mongo/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Mongo/Database/HangfireDbContext.cs

If you want to read it through some API I would search in the `MongoMonitoringAPI` namespace

https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/Hangfire.Mongo/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Mongo/MongoMonitoringApi.cs